# Installing LibNFC on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nfc

I have some NFC chips I want to be able to read with my ubuntu installation,I have a PN532 Breakout board, and I want to install LibNFC so I can modify and read them. I have been following a [tutorial](https://firefart.at/post/how-to-crack-mifare-classic-cards/) and the steps are like this:

```
apt-get install autoconf libtool libusb-dev libpcsclite-dev build-essential
wget https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/releases/download/libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc-1.7.1.tar.bz2
tar -jxvf libnfc-1.7.1.tar.bz2
cd libnfc-1.7.1
autoreconf -vis
./configure --with-drivers=all --sysconfdir=/etc --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir /etc/nfc
sudo mkdir /etc/nfc/devices.d
```

However I get stuck at

```
make
```

I get a version mismatch error, however I dont know how to solve it, any research has been useless, here is the error code fragment.

```
(CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && autoheader) rm -f stamp-h1 touch config.h.in cd . && /bin/bash ./config.status config.h config.status: creating config.h make all-recursive make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/libnfc-1.7.1'
Making all in libnfc
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc' Making all in chips
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/chips' CC libnfcchips_la-pn53x.lo
libtool: Version mismatch error. This is libtool 2.4.6 Debian-2.4.6-0.1, but the
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.4.2.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6 Debian-2.4.6-0.1
libtool: and run autoconf again.
Makefile:397: recipe for target 'libnfcchips_la-pn53x.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [libnfcchips_la-pn53x.lo] Error 63
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/chips'
Makefile:613: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc'
Makefile:478: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/libnfc-1.7.1'
Makefile:385: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Update**: I instead downloaded from [this site](http://bintray.com/nfc-tools/sources/libnfc) (it's in the wiki page) and followed the file INSTALL (with a necessary tweak)

1. > ./configure --prefix=/usr
2. > make
3. > sudo make install

That will do it

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `libtool-bin` package